# Twitter share in multiple share using react-naive-share library (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share)

Tags: react-native, twitter

I am using this https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share library for implementing share but in multi share option its not showing twitter in   sharing try. I am sharing base64 image. Following is my sharing code -

```
 const shareOptions = {
  title: 'Title',
  message: 'Message',
  urls: reviewShare.state.blobArr
};
Share.open(shareOptions)
.then((res) => { console.log(res) })
.catch((err) => { err && console.log(err); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue by following

```
//for more than one base64 image 
const shareOptions = {
  title: 'Title',
  message: 'Message',
  urls: reviewShare.state.blobArr
};

// when only one base64 image
shareOptions = {
    title: 'Title',
    message: 'Message',
    url: reviewShare.state.blobArr[0],
  };
```